# Where's the NPC that gives a free Surf-wielding Pokemon if you don't have one somehow?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

Where's the NPC that gives a free Surf-wielding Pokemon if you don't have one somehow?

Or did I hear wrong about that being a new anti-softlocking measure in later games of the series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be talking about the [Level 15 Tentacool you are gifted in Cianwood City](https://www.serebii.net/heartgoldsoulsilver/gift.shtml) in Heart Gold and Soul Silver if you have released or transferred all but 1 Pokémon and that one doesn't know Surf or Fly. It doesn't have Surf, but you can of course teach it Surf (it being an HM).